# How to pop-up a standard Edit-record modal in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal, edit

The modal that I want to pop-up can be seen, for instance, by clicking Edit in the dropdown menu in the related list of Opportunities for an Account.

To do this in Aura, Salesforce gives [this description](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_modals.htm), which involves firing a force:editRecord event. But I am not programming in Aura, I am doing 100% LWC.

So I tried to emulate it in LWC like this:

```
const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('force:editRecord', { recordId: selectedItemValue });
this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
```

But that doesn't do anything.

So: how to pop-up that standard Edit-record modal? It doesn't have to involve events, in fact I'd prefer a method without them. It just seems a bit complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use lightning navigation service.

1. Import the navigation in lwc.

`import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";`

2. Extend the `NavigationMixin` class in your lwc component.

`export default class YourComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {`

2. Use the below code to open the edit page.

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: recordId, // pass the record id here.
        actionName: 'edit',
    },
});
```

[Documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate).

Comment: But the question was asking about popping this page up in a **modal** - this just navigates to a new page, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope, it pops up the standard edit form on the same page. @jbyrd

Comment: Ohhh - is that b/c of the `actionName: 'edit'`? If we had set that to `view`, it would then navigate to a new page?

Comment: correct @jbyrd, in case of view it navigates but in case edit it doesn't

Comment: So then is there a way to get the view into a modal without navigating?

Comment: yes you need to customize that with slds modal and lightning-record-form in the edit mode. @jbyrd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128498/discussion-between-jbyrd-and-rahul-gawale).

Comment: @RahulGawale, thank you so much for sharing your knowledge! I got this to work on my LWC, and as a brand new developer with limited LWC knowledge, this saves me a ton of time! Thank you!!

Comment: @MiguelDiaz thanks! I am glad this is helpful to you.